# Finding $L_2$ norm given uniform norm

Tags: numerical-methods, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

> Assume that a continuous function $f(x)$ has uniform norm 5 on the
>   interval [1,4]. What is the largest possible value of the $L_2$-norm of
>   $f(x)$ on the intervals [1,4] and on [2,4]?

From what I understand about norms, the $L_2$ norm is greater than the $L_\infty$ norm...and I don't see a bound of sorts. How would I deduce the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if the uniform norm of f is 5 on [1,4] then $$\sup_{x\in [1,4]} |f(x)|=5$$

$$\int_{1}^{4}|f(x)|^2 dx \leq \int_{1}^{4} 5^2 dx $$

$$\int_{2}^{4}|f(x)|^2 dx \leq \int_{2}^{4} 5^2 dx $$

I think you might have been confused by the fact that "$L_2$ is greater than the uniform norm". In fact it is true that some norms are greater than others but they can be bounded by a smaller norm up to a constant. For instance in $\mathbb{R^n}$ in general $L_1\geq L_{\infty}$  but $L_1\leq n L_{\infty}$.

Comment: That's what I thought... but I told myself that was too simple to make sense lol

Comment: Yes I think the confusing part is that you can bound "bigger norms" with "smaller norms". However I think, correct me if I am wrong, that if two norms generate the same topology they will bound each other by a constant.